# Python - List - string value change

Tags: python, list, class, format

I have a list of `am = ['a:hull', 'b:2', 'c:3']`

I want to have `am = ['a:london', 'b:2', 'c:3']` by using a function to change hull to london, without changing the rest.

I have tried to `am = {a:london}`, but it changes the whole list and i want to keep other information as it was

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `am[0] = "a:london"`?

Comment: `am = {a:london}` doesn't change the list at all. It simply assigns a brand new dictionary to the name `am`

Answer (score 1):

You can access list items by using indexes, and the same way to change items.
If you know the index (location) of the item in your list then you can do:

```py
am[0] = "a:london"
```

Where 0 is the index of the item.

Comment: weirdly, when i use am[0] i still get the full list 'a:hull', 'b:2', 'c:3' but without square brackets (the original data also has dtype: object at the end)

Answer (score -2):

you can use the built in replace() function in python.

```
strings = ['a:hull', 'b:2', 'c:3']

new_strings = []

for string in strings:
    new_string = string.replace("a:hull","a:london")
 
    new_strings.append(new_string)

print(new_strings)
```

output would be ['a:london', 'b:2', 'c:3']

Comment: Why would you create a new list, and moreover iterating over the entire list, instead of just modifying one item